# Mscomct2.ocx Can't register win 8.1

Tags: vba, excel, mscomct2.ocx

I have windows embedded 8.1 Industry Pro (64bit) and office 2010. I did everything that I was supposed to do ;

Just extract the .ocx file from the .cab file and Copy to the system folder c:\windows\sysWOW64 for 64 bit systems
Use regsvr32 through the command prompt admin to register the file "regsvr32 c:\windows\sysWOW64\mscomct2.ocx"
But when I go to additional controls, there's no "microsoft date and time picker."

What can I do ?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hardworking days finally I found my problem. My problem was office64 bit edition not supports every activex like mscomct2.ocx when I installed office32 bit problem solved.